# machine learning ranking & DB full text search ranking

Tags: sql-server, machine-learning, full-text-search, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am doing a DB Full Text Search Project, I need little assistance to start. The Database which I am going to use is SQL Server 2014 and ORACLE DB, we have huge amounts of data in our disks. I have collected some information regarding the DB full text search and ranking through sql server documentation, but now my guide says why don't you go for Learning to Rank of Machine learning concepts. I have no idea about it, so I need information about it and does it has any ranking algorithms and which can I go for and how to do as well

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I believe you need to research and study about those concepts. I doubt you get an answer here.

Comment: I think you are right, but I didn't understand the flow how to start and connection for the next steps, do you have any info,

I went to that page FLICKER has no information related to me